# Sql Server 2008 Error 0x800706be

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I encounter this **error:** "`The remote procedure call faile. [0x800706be]`"

try to search for a soln but I haven't seen one that solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/569ee2d4-0805-40e2-a4f0-10f7d573fd75/sql-server-configuration-manager-remote-procedure-call-failed0x800706be?forum=sqltools

Comment: be more specific about the exception. How and When you are getting the same.

Comment: I add image to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

This error is assosiated with a faulty `.mof` registration. You should re-register them using

```
mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, I have done this so many times but I still encounter the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to my problem.. I just need to update my SQL 2008 to service pack 2.